# fill listView from a HashMap data passed from another activity, android

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I am writing an android application to view nearby locations using Google places API, my application consists of two activity, the first activity finds the nearby locations, store info about these locations in a HashMap, and displays them on a map. 
in the second activity I want to get the names of locations from the HashMap from the first activity and display them in a ListView.

the first activity:

```
 HashMap<String, String> hmPlace;
```

protected void onPostExecute(List> list){

```
        // Clears all the existing markers
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            //HashMap<String, String>
            hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

           // listP[i]=hmPlace.get("place_name");
            Log.d("places=",hmPlace.get("place_name"));

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);



            // Setting the title for the marker.
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Linking Marker id and place reference
            mMarkerPlaceLink.put(m.getId(), hmPlace.get("reference"));
        }  
    }
```

I passed the HashMap like this:

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_airports.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.example.dashboard_our.hmPlace",hmPlace);

                startActivity(intent);
```

I get the values from the HashMap in the second activity :

```
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < places1.size(); ++i) {

                list.addAll(places1.values());

            }
```

where places1 is HashMap I got from another activity :

```
HashMap<String, String> places1=(HashMap<String, String>) extras.getSerializable("com.example.dashboard_our.hmPlace");
```

but It only brings the first element and print it many times

this is the rest of the second activity:

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        list.remove(item);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        view.setAlpha(1);
                      }
                    });
              }

            });
          }

          private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
              for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
              String item = getItem(position);
              return mIdMap.get(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
              return true;
            }

          }
```

Comment: where is the code to get array list from intent???

Comment: do u know about data controller class dude save all data in that class and use it everywhere

Comment: What is `hmPlace` here, you are sending `hmPlace` not full Hashmap

Comment: Don't just pass data around like that, you will lose all control when there are so many activity interact together :(

Comment: @BhanuSharma How can I do that?

Comment: @HarishGodara hmPlace is the HashMap I am passing to the second activity

Comment: @autobot_101 what I can do then?? :)

Comment: ok i will explain all in my answer :)

Comment: make the hashmap as public static  and access the hashmap from another activity..simple

Comment: @Karthi I can access the HashMap, but it only prints the first element of it and prints it many times!!

Comment: @roa.tah You can have SharedData class which plays the role of data-router. I take this for example, you may want to initial an instance with idea of "data from which activity to which activity".
[CODE]
ShareData.getInstance(FromActivity.class, ToActivty.class).putObject(Key, Data);
[/CODE]
off-topic --> sorry :)

Comment: can you please show your print code that you have used in another activity

Comment: please get the value by these way hashMap.get("key") and add it to list

Comment: @Karthi it prints the name of one element only.ow could I change the for loop to print all items

Comment: yes correct do it and let me know

Comment: @Karthi I used hashMap.get("key"), but it prints the first element.. what is wrong??!!!

Answer (score 0):

make one datacontroller class like this

public class DataController {

```
    private static DataController ref;

    public static DataController getInstance()
    {
        if(ref==null)
            ref = new DataController();

        return ref;
    }
```

public HashMap hashmap_datacntrlr = new HashMap();

}

from this you get one singlton class which has only one instance in whole app now u just make any datatype which you want to use and save like i mention hashmap now just do this where u get your DATA and save in data controller like this

```
DataController datacntrl;
```

in on create

```
datacntrl = DataController.getInstance();
```

and excess hasmap like datacntrl.hashmap_datacntrlr = PASTE YOUR DATA WHICH IS MUST HAVE SAME DATATYPE;

now in your target class again make datacontoller instance and excess and get datacntrl.hashmap_datacntrlr at where u want to show your data

its call caching some time when we use old data and not trigger again and again from server :)

may be it will help u to achieve your target 
BEST OF LUCK DUDE :)